# How to run code on (re)loading page but not when the component rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rerender

I have a React/Next application and I need to send an event to Google Tag Manager whenever a page with search results **(re)loads**:

- When it's initially loaded
- When the user goes to one of the results and then navigates back
- When the user refreshes the page (and the same set of results gets displayed)

But besides that, I have a requirement **not** to send an event to GTM in case that the component which is used in that page **rerenders** for any other reason (meaning if the inquiryKey and the results do not change, but it gets rerendered because of some event in it or in its parent or whatever else could be the reason).

With the code that I currently have, when I `console.log(windows.dataLayer)` in the browser console everything looks fine, but the test in which I'm using `rerender` is failing. Here's what I have so far:

Parent page:

```
export const ResultsContent: React.FC<ResultsContentProps> = ({
  hasResults,
  inquiryKey,
}) => {  
  return hasResults ? <ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} /> : <NoResults />;
};
```

Results Component:

```
export const ResultsComponent: React.FC<ResultsComponentProps> = ({
  inquiryKey,
}) => {
  // Get results from Redux, calculated based on the form inputs on the previous page
  const results = useSelector(getResults);
  const gtm = useGoogleTagManager();

  /* THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART */
      useEffect(() => {
        gtm.push(createEvent(results)); // makes an event object in a format that we need
      }, []); // empty dependency array to prevent it from running multiple times

  return (/* Component body */);
}
```

For the dependency array I tried: `[], [results], [...results], [inquiryKey, results] and [inquiryKey, ...results]`, but no success. I also tried `useCallback` instead of `useEffect`, but that breaks even more tests...

Here's the test which is failing:

```
it('should contain only one event when rerendered', () => {
    const inquiryKey = 'abc123';
    const { rerender } = render(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />);
    rerender(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />);
    expect(
      window.dataLayer.filter((el) => el.event === `event_name_goes_here`).length,
    ).toBe(1); // It fails, since it found 2 elements
  });
```

...and two more tests which are passing:

```
it('should contain only one event when rendered only once', () => {
    render(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />);
    expect(
      window.dataLayer.filter((el) => el.event === `event_name_goes_here`).length,
    ).toBe(1);
  });

it('should contain three events when rendered three times', () => {
    render(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />);
    render(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />);
    render(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />);
    expect(
      window.dataLayer.filter((el) => el.event === `event_name_goes_here`).length,
    ).toBe(3);
  });
```

I'm not sure if I wrote the failing test correctly... Does the `rerender` method really rerenders a component? What's the difference between this and calling `render` again?

**Edit:**

As @adsy proposed, I added a few lines to the `ResultsComponent`:

```
const counter = useRef<number>(0);
console.log('*** COUNTER ***', counter.current);
counter.current++;
```

When I run only the problematic test, here's the output:

```
console.log
*** COUNTER *** 0
at log (src/components/ResultsComponent/ResultsComponent.tsx:63:11)
console.log
*** COUNTER *** 1
at log (src/components/ResultsComponent/ResultsComponent.tsx:63:11)
console.log
*** COUNTER *** 2
at log (src/components/ResultsComponent/ResultsComponent.tsx:63:11)

Warning: Cannot update a component (`SomeBannerComponent`) while rendering a different component (`TestProviders`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `TestProviders`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
        at store (/some_path/TestProviders.tsx:67:3)
        at wrapper

      25 |   return render(<ResultsComponent inquiryKey={inquiryKey} />, {
      26 |     init(store) {
    > 27 |       store.dispatch(
         |             ^
      28 |         doSaveInquiryInputs(
      29 |           inquiryKey,
      30 |           {

... (full stack trace goes here) ...
 at rerender (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:178:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ResultsComponent/ResultsComponent.test.tsx:249:5)
```

(line 249 is the line where I call the `rerender` method)

...and then below that two logs again:

```
console.log
*** COUNTER *** 0
at log (src/components/ResultsComponent/ResultsComponent.tsx:63:11)
console.log
*** COUNTER *** 1
at log (src/components/ResultsComponent/ResultsComponent.tsx:63:11)
console.log
```

Comment: Is the failing test defined after the other 2 successful ones, in the same suite? And does the failing test still fail if you change its `it(...)` to `it.only(...)`? Seems like a possible test bleed, because you've got a global that is mutated between tests and there's no automatic clear down performed by jest between tests within a suite (unless  `useGoogleTagManager` cleans up after itself on unmount).

Comment: @adsy They are all in the same `describe` block. There are `beforeEach` and `afterEach` methods, but they are only starting and stopping the server (we're using `msw`). The test fails even with `it.only`.

Comment: Hmmm, that probably rules it out. Most likely, since the others pass anyway, the `useGoogleTagManager` cleans up the global on unmount. And running with `it.only` also blows any chance of test bleed -- though id continue to debug with that to isolate the issue. To confirm if the parent is unmounting/remounting, you could try putting in the component  a `const counter = useRef<number>(0)` and then  `console.log(counter.current)` and `counter.current++` just underneath. Then observe output in the test. If it's entirely remounting instead of a simple re-render you'd notice it reset back to 0.

Comment: @adsy The output was too long for the comment. I edited the original question and added it to the bottom.

Comment: Ok this does indeed prove beyond doubt its actually completely remounting. Im immediately drawn to the error in your output. Where does `TestProviders` come into this? Do you have some wrapper around react testing library render?

Comment: @adsy Yes, we do, and we've just concluded that there might be an issue with our testing wrappers. So apparently everything that I implemented was correct, I also still know how to write tests and react-testing-library is also working fine :).

Comment: Yeh. This is almost certainly because render() was wrapped and rerender was not, or differences between those impl's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved - there was something wrong with our wrapper, so it was rerendering components too many times for some reason.